# Docker Container Unique name issue in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, docker-compose

I have couple of services, out of which one of them is scaled. Docker compose file looks like the following (for the particular service)

```yaml
  nt.authservice.service:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}authserviceapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: services/AuthService/AuthService.Api/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
    networks:
      nt.common.network:
      nt.authservice.network:
    depends_on:
      - nt.authservice.db
```

Notice that I have not specified the container name. However, when I run the docker compose from Visual Studio, I get the following error.

```
Error   DT1001  WARNING: The "nt.authservice.service" service is using the custom container name "AuthService.Api". Docker requires each container to have a unique name. Remove the custom name to scale the service.
```

I use **DockerComposeUpArguments** property in docker compose project file to configure the scaling. My .dcprj file looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.Docker.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectVersion>2.1</ProjectVersion>
    <DockerTargetOS>Linux</DockerTargetOS>
    <ProjectGuid>88fac380-9f80-441f-a86d-765d39b0f9a9</ProjectGuid>
    <DockerComposeUpArguments> --scale nt.authservice.service=3 -d</DockerComposeUpArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="docker-compose.override.yml">
      <DependentUpon>docker-compose.yml</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="docker-compose.yml" />
    <None Include=".dockerignore" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Note:**
Please note that this however works if attempt to run the docker compose without visual studio. All the services including the scaled services are created successfully.

```
docker-compose -f server\nt.microservice\docker-compose.yml -f server\nt.microservice\docker-compose.override.yml up --scale nt.authservice.service=5 -d
```

Could anyone guide me on how to resolve the "custom container name" when running from Visual Studio and also help me understand why error occurs only when running from Visual Studio ?

Comment: Opinion: just dont use vs for anything docker or containers related. There is already an ecosystem of tools for handling docker built by Docker Inc and community, no need for MS to tap their hands into this and maintain another set of tools that just raises incompatibilty issues just like your problem. Also your build, test servers and ci/cd runners probably will not have vs or anything like that so you will need to use "native" docker commands and tools. I am saying this as a c# asp.net dev 50% and devops engineer on .net and not .net projects on the other 50%. I dont even use vs at all.